# Responsive SVG (same font-size) as inline-block

Tags: html, css, svg

I write a manual were I explain what different cube values (1 to 6) mean.

So I have created the cubes as SVG and use the svg as inline in my html. My goal would be that the viewbox or the SVG is repsonsive without javascript. So when i change the font-size of `p.para` from 0.5rem to any other size. The cube should follow the text size.

I tried it with a `<span>` and without it.

Here the HTML code (the cube is just a rectangle)

```css
p.para {
  text-align: justify!important;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}

p.para span {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1rem; 
  height: 1rem;
}

p.para svg {
  height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  bla bla foo bar foobar bla bla
  <span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
      <rect width="20" height="20" rx="5" 
      fill="blue" />
    </svg>
  </span>
  bla bla foo bar foobar bla bla.
  More text and even more text.
</p>
```

At the moment the SVG has always the same size, and is not relative or responsive to the `p` font size.

Comment: Mostly, your problem is a typo. The selector should be `svg`, not `.svg`

Comment: Good gotcha. I will correct the code above. But the issue still exist

Comment: `p.para > svg` - that `svg` element is not a child of the paragraph, so this fails to select it to begin with. And `height: 1rem` would _not_ be relative to the font size of the paragraph. `rem` is relative to the font size of the _root element_.

Comment: THANKS! Yes. I changed from `rem` to `em` and removed the child selctor. And it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) I was able to fix it.

And even the code is now simpler. :-)

- I removed the child-selector `>`
- I removed the styling for the `<svg>` at all

```css
p.para {
  text-align: justify!important;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p.para span {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em; 
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  bla bla foo bar foobar bla bla
  <span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
      <rect width="20" height="20" rx="5" 
      fill="blue" />
    </svg>
  </span>
  bla bla foo bar foobar bla bla.
  More text and even more text.
</p>
```